# Surround parentheses with its content by extra parentheses

Tags: search, vim, replace, parentheses

I have lines that I want to convert from

```
(variable=value)
```

to

```
((variable=value))
```

How should I go about doing that from the vim command line?

Comment: Your title says "remove" but your question describes adding parens. Which is it?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusing title. I meant to remove single parentheses and replace them with double parentheses.

Comment: Changed heading to better reflect that intention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can use following substitute command

```
:%s/(.*)/(&)/g
```

where

```
.* - all strings of characters of any length and
&  - the whole matched pattern
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. What if I want to change from (variable=value) to ( variable=value ) ? Basically adding whitespace in the parentheses.

Comment: Does it serve the purpose https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737490/how-to-add-space-between-parenthesis-and-quotes-on-save

Answer (score 1):

This is commonly done with the [surround.vim plugin](https://vim.sourceforge.io/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697): First select the single-parentheses block with `va(`, then surround with another set of parens via `S(`.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution (if you have only this pattern in the line):

```
 :.s/.*/(&)

 .s ................... current line substitute
 .* ................... everything
 ( .................... open paren
 & .................... all pattern searched
 ) .................... close paren
```

Or

```
 :norm! I(^[A)
```

OBS: The simbol `^[` should be typed with <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-[</kbd>.

Don't forget you can repat the last command `:` in the current line by typing `@:` and in the subsequent lines `@@`.

In normal mode With no plugins you can do this (if the pattern does not repeat a lot):

```
ca( ................ start changing the pattern (text goes to default register ")
( .................. start typing open parenthesis
Ctrl-r" ............ insert default register 
) .................. close parenthesis
```

OBS: This action is repeatable by typing `.`